# An exception occurred during a WebClient request in C# from FileUpload

Tags: c#, ftp, webclient

I am getting the following exception whilst trying to upload file to ft: An exception occurred during a WebClient request.

```
 protected void UploadFile(string ftpServer, string filename)
            {
                using (System.Net.WebClient client = new System.Net.WebClient())
                {
                    client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password");
                    client.UploadFile(ftpServer  + new FileInfo(filename).Name, "STOR", filename);
                }
            }
```

the above method is being accessed from:

```
try
                    {
                        UploadFile("ftp://website//Images//",FileUpload1.FileName);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {

                        ShowError(ex.Message);
                    }
```

Details of Error:

> Could not find file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft
>   Shared\DevServer\10.0\test.jpg'.

PS: File is located in Pictures folders not the given folder above.

Comment: Well what are the *details* of the exception? You should look at the complete stack trace.

Comment: @JonSkeet 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException:'

Comment: It looks like you're trying to upload to FTP posted asp.net file from FileUpload. Problem is - file not exists yet physically on your server, it will exist as soon as you will save it.  Good usecase is in official documentation, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.postedfile%28v=vs.110%29.aspx You should reconsider your logic, probably, by saving file to server first.

Comment: Use the *full* pathname for the file.  Not just "test.jpg", use "c:\foo\bar\test.jpg".

Comment: @Dmitriy Tried saving file to server first then uploading to ftp I got the following error: "The remote server returned an error: (550)"

Comment: @rikket, it looks like exactly what ftp 550 error is - you can google or SO for details, but, in general: check, if you have permissions to write to this ftp, to specified folder, with username and password you provided as credentials. You can test it, for example, using FileZilla.